# How to use BETWEEN in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a project using symfony2. I have a date_started and date_ended and I am planning to use BETWEEN instead of  >= and <= . I just want to ask any idea on how should I implement it using symfony2? Since my work doesn't work. Here is my sample code:

Repository :

```
public function getAllTransaction($rNumber,$gNumber,$senderId,$receiverId,$docType,$direction,$startDate,$endDate,$page = 1, $limit = 10) {
         $em = $this->getEntityManager();
         $query = $em->createQuery(
           'SELECT partial a.{supplierTransactionDetailId, rNumber, pNumber, invNumber, anNumber, adNumber, amount}, 
            partial b.{supplierTransactionId, transactionDate, senderId, receiverId, isaNumber, gsNumber, fileName}, 
            partial c.{supplierDocTypeId, docType, direction} 
            FROM SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail a 
            JOIN a.supplierTransaction b 
            JOIN b.supplierDocType c
            WHERE (a.rNumber LIKE :rNumber OR a.pNumber LIKE :rNumber 
                  OR a.invNumber LIKE :rNumber 
                  OR a.anNumber LIKE :rNumber 
                  OR a.adNumber LIKE :rNumber )
            AND b.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber
            AND b.senderId LIKE :senderId
            AND b.receiverId LIKE :receiverId
            AND c.docType LIKE :docType
            AND c.direction LIKE :direction
            AND b.transactionDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate



            ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc'
          )
          ->setParameter('rNumber', "%$rNumber%")
          ->setParameter('gsNumber', "%$gsNumber%")
          ->setParameter('senderId', "%$senderId%")
          ->setParameter('receiverId' , "%$receiverId%")
          ->setParameter('docType',"%$docType%")
          ->setParameter('direction', "%$direction%")
          ->setParameter('startDate', "%$startDate%")
          ->setParameter('endDate', "%$endDate%")
          ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) *$limit )
          ->setMaxResults($limit);

         $paginator = new Paginator ($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false );
         $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);

         return $paginator;
      }
```

This code display all the transaction with pagination and can also search, but then when I put the last part the **`transactionDate with Between it doesn't display nothing.`** .

Controller :

```
public function trackAction(Request $request,$page){
        $rNumber = $request->query->get('rNumber');
        $gsNumber = $request->query->get('gsNumber');
        $senderId = $request->query->get('senderId');
        $receiverId = $request->query->get('receiverId');
        $docType = $request->query->get('docType');
        $direction = $request->query->get('direction');
        $startDate = $request->query->get('startDate');
        $endDate = $request->query->get('endDate');

        $max_records = 10;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $trans = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail')->getAllTransaction($rNumber,$gsNumber,$senderId,$receiverId,$docType,$direction,$startDate,$endDate,$page , 10);

        $count = $trans->count();
        $pagination = array(
            'page' => $page,
            'route' => 'supplier_tracking',
            'route_params' => array()
        );

        if ($max_records > 0 ){
            $pagination['pages_count'] = max(ceil($count / $max_records), 1);
        }

        return $this->render('SupplierBundle:Supplier:tracking.html.twig',array('trans' => $trans, 'pagination' => $pagination));


    }
```

**UPDATE**

In my database  transactionDate is formatted something like this :

2015-05-18 18:10:00 for it is datetime. and in my form ,,, startdate and enddate is input type of date.

Comment: Still not clear what your problem is. Are you sure your query actually matches anything? Are your dates in the right format? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: everything is working it can search already whatever I wanted, it is just the transaction date that is not working and due to this it returns nothing, that's why I don't know why this is happening,. Lastly, what do you mean by my date format?

Comment: Show some sample data. We can't tell from your question how your dates are stored. What data types did you use? Are $startDate and $endDate formatted correctly (`yyyy-mm-dd`)? We can't tell. If, for example, you are using a DATE field in MySQL and your start and end dates are formatted like `May 1, 2015` or `05/01/2015`, that would explain your problem. Show us your data!

Comment: my dates are stored something like shown in my updated question, and for the datatype i am using datetime,

Comment: Unfortunately, there is still not enough information here. You have a lot of requirements joined with `AND` in your `WHERE` clause. If any of those fails to match a row, it is excluded. Your result could be empty for many reasons, but we can't guess where the error (if there is one) is. You should accept one of the two answers (mine or @RiggsFolly's) because they both address the syntax problem in your `BETWEEN` clause, which is what you asked about. Then, ask your question about why your result is empty as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have removed the LIKE for the BETWEEN syntax, as per @EdCottrell answer. I think you also need to change these 2 lines to remove the `%` used in the LIKE syntax.

```
->setParameter('startDate', "$startDate")
->setParameter('endDate', "$endDate")
```

Also do you actually need everything `LIKE`'d like that. It all seems a bit wooly. As most of those fields appear to be numbers I doubt that the LIKE syntax is actually required, although I am only guessing that they are numbers from their names.

**Re your comment about numbers**

Try this then, removing all the likes and passing the values as numbers and not strings.

```
public function getAllTransaction(
                                 $rNumber,$gNumber,$senderId,$receiverId,
                                 $docType,$direction,$startDate,$endDate,
                                 $page = 1, $limit = 10
                                ) 
{
     $em = $this->getEntityManager();
     $query = $em->createQuery(
       'SELECT    partial a.{supplierTransactionDetailId, rNumber, pNumber, invNumber, anNumber, adNumber, amount}, 
                  partial b.{supplierTransactionId, transactionDate, senderId, receiverId, isaNumber, gsNumber, fileName}, 
                  partial c.{supplierDocTypeId, docType, direction} 
        FROM SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail a 
           JOIN a.supplierTransaction b 
           JOIN b.supplierDocType c
        WHERE (  a.rNumber = :rNumber 
              OR a.pNumber = :rNumber 
              OR a.invNumber = :rNumber 
              OR a.anNumber = :rNumber 
              OR a.adNumber = :rNumber )
          AND b.gsNumber = :gsNumber
          AND b.senderId = :senderId
          AND b.receiverId = :receiverId
          AND c.docType = :docType
          AND c.direction = :direction
          AND b.transactionDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
        ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc'
      )
      ->setParameter('rNumber', $rNumber)
      ->setParameter('gsNumber', $gsNumber)
      ->setParameter('senderId', $senderId)
      ->setParameter('receiverId' , $receiverId)
      ->setParameter('docType', $docType)
      ->setParameter('direction', $direction)
      ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
      ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
      ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) *$limit )
      ->setMaxResults($limit);

     // add this debug code to check the generated query
     // you could try and run this using phpMyadmin or
     // whatever mysql tools you use. If taht gets errors
     // come back here an mod the generator

     echo $query->getSQL();

     $paginator = new Paginator ($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false );
     $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);

     return $paginator;
  }
```

***RE: I found this***

This is the result of the `echo $query->getSQL();` and is the query that QueryBuilder has generated from all your inputs.

I would copy/paste that into something like phpMyAdmin or whatever tool you use to look at your mysql database, replace the `?` with the actual parameters that you were using and try and run it.

My guess is that because it is such a complex query you have created an impossible requirement and it is either failing in the compile phase or is just returning no results. You can then play with the query until you get it right and then change the PHP script accordingly.

```
SELECT e0_.supplier_transaction_detail_id AS supplier_transaction_detail_id0, 
       e0_.r_number AS r_number1, 
       e0_.p_number AS p_number2, 
       e0_.inv_number AS inv_number3, 
       e0_.an_number AS an_number4, 
       e0_.ad_number AS ad_number5, 
       e1_.supplier_transaction_id AS supplier_transaction_id7, 
       e1_.sender_id AS sender_id8, 
       e1_.receiver_id AS receiver_id9, 
       e1_.transaction_date AS transaction_date11,
       e1_.gs_number AS gs_number12,
       e2_.supplier_doc_type_id AS supplier_doc_type_id14,
       e2_.doc_type AS doc_type15, 
       e2_.direction AS direction16, 
       e0_.supplier_transaction_id AS supplier_transaction_id17, 
       e1_.supplier_doc_type_id AS supplier_doc_type_id18 
   FROM supplier_transaction_detail e0_ 
      INNER JOIN supplier_transaction e1_ ON e0_.supplier_transaction_id = e1_.supplier_transaction_id 
      INNER JOIN supplier_doc_type e2_ ON e1_.supplier_doc_type_id = e2_.supplier_doc_type_id 
   WHERE (e0_.r_number = ? OR 
          e0_.p_number = ? OR 
          e0_.inv_number = ? OR 
          e0_.an_number = ? OR 
          e0_.ad_number = ?)

      AND e1_.gs_number = ? 
      AND e1_.sender_id = ? 
      AND e1_.receiver_id = ? 
      AND e2_.doc_type = ? 
      AND e2_.direction = ? 
       OR e1_.transaction_date BETWEEN ? AND ? 
   ORDER BY e1_.transaction_date DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: sorry not sure what that ment. _Yes they are_ what

Comment: numbers the rNumber and so on,,

Comment: It gives no result, and I found this :

Comment: SELECT e0_.supplier_transaction_detail_id AS supplier_transaction_detail_id0, e0_.r_number AS r_number1, e0_.p_number AS p_number2, e0_.inv_number AS inv_number3, e0_.an_number AS an_number4, e0_.ad_number AS ad_number5, e1_.supplier_transaction_id AS supplier_transaction_id7, e1_.sender_id AS sender_id8, e1_.receiver_id AS receiver_id9, e1_.transaction_date AS transaction_date11,

Comment: e1_.gs_number AS gs_number12e2_.supplier_doc_type_id AS supplier_doc_type_id14, e2_.doc_type AS doc_type15, e2_.direction AS direction16, e0_.supplier_transaction_id AS supplier_transaction_id17, e1_.supplier_doc_type_id AS supplier_doc_type_id18 FROM supplier_transaction_detail e0_ INNER JOIN supplier_transaction e1_ ON e0_.supplier_transaction_id = e1_.supplier_transaction_id INNER JOIN supplier_doc_type e2_ ON e1_.supplier_doc_type_id = e2_.supplier_doc_type_id WHERE (e0_.r_number = ? OR e0_.p_number = ? OR e0_.inv_number = ? OR e0_.an_number = ? OR e0_.ad_number = ?)

Comment: AND e1_.gs_number = ? AND e1_.sender_id = ? AND e1_.receiver_id = ? AND e2_.doc_type = ? AND e2_.direction = ? OR e1_.transaction_date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY e1_.transaction_date DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Comment: what to I need to do?

Comment: See ***I found this*** section of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `LIKE` in a `BETWEEN` clause; it's just `BETWEEN x AND y`:

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail a 
    JOIN a.supplierTransaction b 
    JOIN b.supplierDocType c
WHERE b.transactionDate 
    BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc
```

Comment: @Errorhere please be more specific. What isn't working, where? What isn't happening that should, or is happening that shouldn't? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: @Errorhere I would be suspicious of your table name and the JOIN syntax, but you haven't given much info about what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have any errors. Scenario is something like this, I follow your code, but it doesn't give any results, because originally it will display all the transaction before I search but then, it doesn't give me any display,

Comment: I really don't know what to do with this one,,, can you give further help if its okay with you?

Comment: @Errorhere I'm sorry, but you really haven't given us enough information to spot any further problems. I don't know what you mean by "originally it will display all the transaction before I search but then, it doesn't give me any display."

Comment: I'll just update by question and post some related codes

Answer (score 0):

Hey to setup correct query it have to look like this:

```
SELECT ..
FROM ..
WHERE (SELECT .. FROM ..) BETWEEN .. AND ..
```

I set up for you example based on your code. Remember to add more queries.
So example for this query with sub query should look something similar to this:

```
$subQueryDQL = $qbv->select('a.parameter')
    ->from('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail', 'a')
    ...
    ->getDQL();

$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->between(
    sprintf('(%s)', $subQueryDQL),
    $filter->getStartDate()->getTimestamp(),
    $filter->getEndDate()->getTimestamp()
));
```

Your code would look something like:
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

```
$query = $qb->select('a.supplierTransactionDetailId, a.rNumber, a.pNumber, a.invNumber, a.anNumber, a.adNumber, a.amount,
b.supplierTransactionId, b.transactionDate, b.senderId, b.receiverId, b.isaNumber, b.gsNumber, b.fileName,
c.supplierDocTypeId, c.docType, c.direction}')
    ->from("SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail", 'a')
    ->innerJoin('a.supplierTransaction', 'b')
    ->innerJoin('b.supplierDocType', 'c')
    ->add('where', $qb->expr()->between(
        'b.transactionDate',
        ':startDate',
        ':endDate'
    )
    )
    ->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->like('b.senderId', ':senderId')
    )
    ->setParameter('rNumber', "%$rNumber%")
    ->setParameter('gsNumber', "%$gsNumber%")
    ->setParameter('senderId', "%$senderId%")
    ->setParameter('receiverId', "%$receiverId%")
    ->setParameter('docType', "%$docType%")
    ->setParameter('direction', "%$direction%")
    ->setParameter('startDate', "%$startDate%")
    ->setParameter('endDate', "%$endDate%")
    ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $limit)
    ->setMaxResults($limit);

$paginator = new Paginator ($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false);
$paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);

return $paginator;
```

You will have to add more where by yourself.

Comment: w8 a moment let me try to.

Comment: here you go i updated the answer. remember to add missing queries. its an sample based on your code. i havent tested it.